# C Segmentation Fault in printf - dl-lookup.c

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a seg fault while running a C multi-threaded code.
Apparently it runs ok until I try to printf an element from a 2D char array.

I tried to look out for an answer, but nothing seems to solve the problem.

This is the part of the code I'm getting seg fault:

```
k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < TAB_ALT; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < TAB_LARG; j++){
        if(tab[i][j] == 'X'){
            printf("(");
            for(l = 1; l <= possibilidades[k][0]; l++){
                printf("%c", possibilidades[k][l]);
            }
            printf(")    ");
            k++;
        } else {
            printf("%c    ", tab[i][j]); //Seg fault here
        }
    } // Fim for
    printf("\n");
} //Fim for
```

**Edit:** After using `Valgrind` to search for memory leaks, as suggested by `Barmar`, I found that the variable I use to get the thread function return isn't actually getting it. It's supposed to be a char array (seqLinha). In the thread function it's filled fine, but the variable that's supposed to get it's memory address is not.

I think it might be something about the way I'm passing it as argument in pthread_join().

```
typedef struct argPercorre {
    int i;
    char (*tab)[9];
} ArgPercorre;

void *percorre_linha(void *arg){
    ArgPercorre argumento;
    argumento = *(ArgPercorre *)arg;

    int k = argumento.i;
    int l;
    char *seqLinha = (char *) malloc(9*sizeof(char));
    char (*tab)[9] = argumento.tab;

    for(l = 0; l < TAB_LARG; l++){
        seqLinha[l] = tab[k][l];
    }

    return seqLinha;
}

char *seqLinha;
pthread_create(&(thread[0]), NULL, percorre_linha, (void *)argLinha);
pthread_join(thread[0], (void*)seqLinha);
```

The code before seems to work ok, I guess. Those variables are declared and initialized before. If needed I can put the code before this, maybe there's a problem there.

And the GDB error message is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
do_lookup_x (new_hash=359345080, old_hash=<optimized out>, 
result=0x7fffffffdbe0, scope=<optimized out>, i=0, flags=5, skip=0x0, 
undef_map=0x7ffff7ffe2c8) at dl-lookup.c:98
98  dl-lookup.c: No such file or directory.
```

I have no idea what this dl-lookup.c file is.

If you guys need more detail, just tell me and I will provide what's needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A segmentation fault could be caused by misuse of a pointer or a buffer overflow almost anywhere in the program -- it corrupts the heap and the effect might not be noticed until later in the program. Use `valgrind` to debug memory use problems.

Comment: since its apparently crashing on access to the tab[][]-array, it may be helpful to show the definition of that array .

Comment: Most likely you are accessing out of bounds of the array `tab`. You should use the `assert` macro to check that your array indices are within the array range.

Comment: If somebody can put an answer to this question, I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

Here is the solution:

The problem was simply the way I was passing the variable `seqLinha` to the pthread_join() argument, like this:

    pthread_join(thread[0], (void*)seqLinha);

When, actually, it's supposed to be like:

    pthread_join(thread[0], (void*)&seqLinha);

As I have to pass the address of `seqLinha` in order to have it's value modified, and so pointing to the memory space provided by the array initialization in `percorreLinha`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question because I got it right.
The problem was simply the way I was passing the variable `seqLinha` to pthread_join() argument, like this:

```
pthread_join(thread[0], seqLinha);
```

When, actually, it's supposed to be like:

```
pthread_join(thread[0], &seqLinha);
```

As I have to pass the address of `seqLinha` in order to have it's value modified, and so pointing to the memory space provided by the array initialization in `percorreLinha`.

Comment: This cast is wrong in as `pthread_join()` epect `void**`. And in the the first place casting isn't needed at all.